# initialize a form if user press on previous button of the browser

Tags: php, session-variables

I've in my home page a search tool with a form that contain two select/option linked to ajax. if i change the country the list of towns changes also.

Also i've a select that contain a list of number from 1 to 5 that allows users to duplicate other input with jquery

The problem is, users have tendency  to click to the previous button of browser, and try to change other value for new research, but for exemple the list of town is stack to a null value.
Also if the user has duplicated an input three time, the select will shows 3 but there isn't 3 fields cloned.

I want to initialise all my fields if user press on the previous button of browser, i've tried to save a $_SESSION['result'] variable in the page of result, and at home to test if this var isn't empty, and if this var isn't, i'll make a redirection into the home to reset my form, but it didn't works for me!

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['result'])) {
header('Location: home.php');

}
```

How can i solve this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was very simple :)

```
<body onload="init_form()">


function init_form()
    {
    document.forms[0].listeCity.options[0].selected = true;
    document.forms[0].sctRoom.options[0].selected = true;
    }
```

I hope this will help !